# How do I get `cabal repl` to read `.ghci` *after* compiling my project's modules?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I have

```
:m +Control.Monad System.Random.MWC NW.Affix
```

in my `.ghci` file in my project's root directory. I want to load in `NW.Affix` (a module in my project) with `cabal repl`, but it fails immediately like this:

```
Preprocessing executable 'netherworld' for netherworld-0.0.0.0...
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.4.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.3.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-1.1.1.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package primitive-0.5.3.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package vector-0.10.11.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mwc-random-0.13.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package monads-tf-0.1.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package byteable-0.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package cryptohash-0.11.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.5.1 ... linking ... done.

<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘NW.Affix’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

After failing like this, it happily compiles my modules, like so:

```
[ 1 of 14] Compiling NW.Util          ( src/NW/Util.hs, interpreted )
[ 2 of 14] Compiling NW.Stats         ( src/NW/Stats.hs, interpreted )
[ 3 of 14] Compiling NW.Monster       ( src/NW/Monster.hs, interpreted )
[ 4 of 14] Compiling NW.Random        ( src/NW/Random.hs, interpreted )
[ 5 of 14] Compiling NW.Map           ( src/NW/Map.hs, interpreted )
[ 6 of 14] Compiling NW.Player        ( src/NW/Player.hs, interpreted )
[ 7 of 14] Compiling NW.Error         ( src/NW/Error.hs, interpreted )
[ 8 of 14] Compiling NW.Effect        ( src/NW/Effect.hs, interpreted )
[ 9 of 14] Compiling NW.Config        ( src/NW/Config.hs, interpreted )
[10 of 14] Compiling NW.Affix         ( src/NW/Affix.hs, interpreted )
[11 of 14] Compiling NW.Item          ( src/NW/Item.hs, interpreted )
[12 of 14] Compiling NW.State         ( src/NW/State.hs, interpreted )
[13 of 14] Compiling NW.Battle        ( src/NW/Battle.hs, interpreted )
[14 of 14] Compiling Main             ( src/main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: NW.Affix, Main, NW.Battle, NW.Config, NW.Item, NW.Error, NW.Map, NW.Player, NW.Random, NW.State, NW.Stats, NW.Monster, NW.Effect, NW.Util.
```

The current workaraound is to just copy-paste my `.ghci` stuff into `cabal repl` after it's done initializing. Still, is there a way to delay `cabal repl` from reading in my `.ghci` file until *after* it finishes compiling my project's modules?

Comment: Maybe it is because you have to tell GHCi how to find your module.  In that case try `:set -i/path/to/my/files/` before `:m`

Comment: @vivian I tried `:set -i...` with a bunch of different combinations of directories under `./dist` (the place where cabal puts compiled object files), but it didn't work.

Comment: try setting `:set -i..` to where the source files are, not the object files.

Comment: @vivan Tried it with `:set -i./src` (all my source files are in `src`; my project's cabal file says `hs-source-dirs: src` also), but it doesn't work. If I do `:set -i src`, cabal repl complains `Some flags have not been recognized: src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, well I don't really understand it yet, but a "workaround" (if you can call it that) is to break up the `:m` line into `:m` for cabal-installed packages and `:l` for your own ones.

So in my case, I just changed

```
:m +Control.Monad System.Random.MWC NW.Affix
```

to

```
:l NW.Item
:m +Control.Monad System.Random.MWC
```

in my `.ghci` and `cabal repl` works as expected. But it seems a bit roundabout... I mean, if copy/pasting the .ghci after it loads makes it work anyway, why is there a need for this `:m` and `:l` distinction?